# Gridvew Looping for multiple times even when selected least records in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, gridview, foreach

I have a `gridview` in which every row contains a `checkbox` for selection. That selection will be used for `Approve` or `Reject` purpose.

But issue here is If I select `2` rows from the `gridview`  it loops atleast 4-5 times and gives me multiple emails of the same row.

Below is my code. Please suggest.

```
protected void btnApproveCMM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strDate = "";
        string strMailContent = "";
        DataTable dtApprove = new DataTable();
        CommonDB ObjDB = new CommonDB();

        try
        {
            bool flgCMM = false;
            IPColoFields ObjIPColoFields = new App_Code.IPColoFields();
            List<IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails> UMSGroupDetails = (List<IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.UMS.UMSGroupDetails>)Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"];

            Session["lstUMSGroupDetails"] = UMSGroupDetails;
            string strApprove = "";

            if (ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes_CMM"] != null)
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow row in grdDisplayCMMData.Rows)
                {
                    if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkApprRejCMM")).Checked)
                    {
                        Label SAPID_CMM = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSAP_ID_CMM");
                        Label ID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID_CMM");
                        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(ID.Text);

                        ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id = Id;
                        ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_ID = intCurrentGrpId;
                        ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_NAME = strCurrentGrp;
                        ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_ID = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupID;
                        ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_NAME = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupName;
                        ObjIPColoFields.FCA_STATUS = "1";
                        ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY = lblUserName.Text;
                        strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                        strApprove = CommonDB.Approve_IPCOLO_CMMLevel(ObjIPColoFields);

                        if (ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != null || ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != 0)
                        {
                            strMailContent = Get_Email_Content(ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY, SAPID_CMM.Text, strIPCOLO_CMM, Convert.ToString(Id), strDate, "Approved");
                            SendEmail(lblUserName.Text, strMailContent, strIPCOLO_CMM);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            BindCMMData();

            if (flgCMM == false)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please check atleast one row'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Approved successfully'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString() + " " + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            CommonDB.WriteLog("ERROR:" + strErrorMsg, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPCOLO_LOG"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to say what's going on here. It looks like you somehow prepopulate the `ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes_CMM"]` with values of the checked checkboxes. Then loop over that, and inside, loop over all rows in the grid. I would remove the outer loop and just loop over the gridview rows, using `Findcontrol` to get the checkbox on the row and then decide what to do next based on if it's checked or not. Also, this if: `if (ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != null || ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != 0)` is meaningless. The property cannot be both null and 0, so the body of the if will always run.

Comment: @user1429080: should I remove the outer loop and check whether i m getting the expected result ?

Comment: In which event you are assigning List into ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes_CMM"]? You have to debug that event.

Comment: @AamirNakhwa: I am assigning it on `Page_load` event. `if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["CheckedCheckboxes_CMM"] = new List<int>(); }`

Comment: @user1429080: I removed the outer loop and now I am getting the expected results, may be I was getting `id` from that so I used that extra looping for. But now its not needed. I will recheck once again

Comment: @user1429080: after removing the outer loop it loops all the rows which are not checked also, so the logic is not working

Comment: Wait, if you removed the outer loop then how are you able to get only checked records? It will send email on the records which have Unique_Id.

Comment: @AamirNakhwa: See my last comment, :)

Comment: As I wrote, you need to use `Findcontrol` to get the checkbox on each row. Then check if it's checked. If not, continue the loop.

Comment: Alright, you have to find the checkbox the same way you do it for label.
Checkbox chk = (Checkbox)row.FindControl("Your checkboxID");
and then put your code in below condition

if (chk.Checked)
{
//put your code here
}

Comment: @AamirNakhwa: I am writing checkbox in aspx like this `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve/Reject">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprRejCMM" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkApprRejCMM_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: What are you doing in chkApprRejCMM_CheckedChanged event?
Use this 
Checkbox chk = (Checkbox)row.FindControl("chkApprRejCMM");

Comment: i need that event to maintain the state of checked checkboxes

Comment: You don't need that event anymore as you are looping on all the rows and checking the checked boxes here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this code**

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdDisplayCMMData.Rows)
{
      if (((Checkbox)row.FindControl("chkApprRejCMM")).Checked)
      {
      Label SAPID_CMM = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSAP_ID_CMM");

      ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id = Id;
      ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_ID = intCurrentGrpId;
      ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_BY_NAME = strCurrentGrp;
      ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_ID = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupID;
      ObjIPColoFields.UMS_GRP_TO_NAME = UMSGroupDetails[1].GroupName;
      ObjIPColoFields.FCA_STATUS = "1";
      ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY = lblUserName.Text;
      strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();                                                    

      strApprove = CommonDB.Approve_IPCOLO_CMMLevel(ObjIPColoFields);

      if (ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != null || ObjIPColoFields.Unique_Id != 0)
      {
            strMailContent = Get_Email_Content(ObjIPColoFields.LAST_UPDATED_BY, SAPID_CMM.Text, strIPCOLO_CMM, Convert.ToString(Id), strDate, "Approved");
            SendEmail(lblUserName.Text, strMailContent, strIPCOLO_CMM);
      }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I just copied your code and put checkbox checked condition. Now that line is removed

Comment: i m stuck at validation part now, which is outside If condition `BindCMMData();

                if (flgCMM == false)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Please check atleast one row'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Approved successfully'); window.location ='IpColoDefault.aspx';", true);
                }`

Comment: You can put this script on your page. No need to do a postback for this validation.
Do you have jQuery in your project?

Comment: I have updated my whole code in question. have a look

Comment: i was getting alert even if I check one row `Please check atleast one row`

Comment: Put this line 
flgCMM = true;
before Label SAPID_CMM = (Label)row.FindControl("lblSAP_ID_CMM");

Comment: yeah, now its working fine.. let me check all 360 degree so that I can be assure.. will update you once done

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192624/discussion-between-aamir-nakhwa-and-b-n